# Allow internet access for ubuntu

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I am seeking solution to allow internet access at NIC 1 bridged adapter in VirtualBox.

I tested Ubuntu VirtualBox with static and dhcp setting seems not working on NIC 1 adapter primary and secondary nodes.

There two NIC adapter. NIC Adapter 1 points to bridged connection and NIC adapter 2 configure as internal network communication between two nodes.

My platform host is windows operating system. It has VPN client. Kindly advised.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.